# ios and evernote : How can i know which Createnote failed?

Tags: ios, evernote

I'm using Evernote sdk on iOS and it works great.

But sometimes I'm sending several CreateNote methods in a row and, as Evernote sends them asynchronously, if one of them falls in error I can't say which one ...

The CreateNote method returns a Note object when success but a NSError when failure. And this one doesn't tell about which query it was.

How can I know which note creations failed ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Evernote SDK does send the requests asynchronously, but its always one request at a time. So if a request fails, its always the last request that you made.